# How to scroll 10 line vertically with keyboard without moving cursor in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am vim user, I don't like mouse to scroll.

pagedown and pageup is not perfect for me, I want to bindkey for pageup and pagedown with 10 lines scroll or something like that

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Your link, is just a link to this question. @Mark

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `editorScroll` command to scroll the editor any amount you set without moving the cursor from its original position.  For example, in keybindings.json:

```
{
  "key": "alt+m",                // whatever keybinding you like
  "command": "editorScroll",
  "args": {
    "by": "line",
    "to": "down",

    // "revealCursor": false,   // set to true if you did want to move the cursor
                                // false is the default
     "value": 10
  },
  "when": "editorFocus"
},
{
  "key": "shift+alt+m",         // whatever keybinding you like
  "command": "editorScroll",
  "args": {
    "by": "line",
    "to": "up",
    // "revealCursor": false,
    "value": 10
  },
  "when": "editorFocus"
},
```

[complex commands including editorScroll](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted this too, but I find instantaneous scrolling kind of jarring, so I wanted it to be a quick animation.  Stringing together a sequence of `scrollLineDown` or `scrollLineUp` commands achieves that.

I also wanted a secondary command that moved the cursor as well as the editor so that the cursor would stay in place within the editor as you scrolled instead of moving with the text.

### Steps

1. Install the extension [Macro Commander](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jeff-hykin.macro-commander) (or some equivalent) to let you create new commands that are a sequence of existing commands.
2. Add the macros to `settings.json`:

```json
"macros": {
    "scrollEditorDownTen": [
        "scrollLineDown",
        "scrollLineDown",
        "scrollLineDown",
        "scrollLineDown",
        "scrollLineDown",
        "scrollLineDown",
        "scrollLineDown",
        "scrollLineDown",
        "scrollLineDown",
        "scrollLineDown",
    ],
    "scrollEditorAndCursorDownTen": [
        "macros.scrollEditorDownTen",
        { "command": "cursorMove", "args": { "to": "down", "by": "line", "value": 10 } },
    ],
    "scrollEditorUpTen": [
        "scrollLineUp",
        "scrollLineUp",
        "scrollLineUp",
        "scrollLineUp",
        "scrollLineUp",
        "scrollLineUp",
        "scrollLineUp",
        "scrollLineUp",
        "scrollLineUp",
        "scrollLineUp",
    ],
    "scrollEditorAndCursorUpTen": [
        "macros.scrollEditorUpTen",
        { "command": "cursorMove", "args": { "to": "up", "by": "line", "value": 10 } },
    ],
},
```

3. Add hotkeys to `keybindings.json`:

```json
{ "key": "pageup", "command": "macros.scrollEditorUpTen" },
{ "key": "pagedown", "command": "macros.scrollEditorDownTen" },
{ "key": "ctrl+pageup", "command": "macros.scrollEditorAndCursorUpTen" },
{ "key": "ctrl+pagedown", "command": "macros.scrollEditorAndCursorDownTen" },
```